# Auto generating .cs files out of Yaml definitions at compile time

Tags: c#, yaml, t4, auto-generate

Is there a way I could parse a bunch of yaml files (containing API information for all my modules), extract some of its contents and generate a class implementation at compile time in C#?

Here is an example of what my Yaml API files look like:

```
CLASS_NAME: MyClass
PARAMETERS:
  - NAME: Param1
    SIZE: 1
    DEFAULT: 5
    TYPE: INT
    SOME_OTHER_UNUSED_THINGS: Some text
  - NAME: Param2
    SIZE: 5
    DEFAULT: 
       - [0 0 0 0 0]
    TYPE: INT[]
    SOME_OTHER_UNUSED_THINGS: Some text
```

At build time I would like these Yaml files to get parsed and output the corresponding classes in .cs files. Those generated files then need to get compiled in with the project containing these auto-generated files.
Here is the desired output:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass: MyClassBase, IMyClass
    {
        public IParameter<int> Param1{ get; set; }
        public IParameterArray<int[]> Param2{ get; set; }

        public MyClass()
        {
            MyClassName = this.GetType().Name;
        }
    }
}
```

I had a bit of a look at T4 templates, but I cannot figure out how to execute code such as deserialising my yaml files and interpret them.

Comment: Not sure but maybe the [CodeDom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/using-the-codedom) could help you out. The code dom lets you write code which generate classes. So inside this code you could read the yaml and go on from there. The only real issue you'll have is that those would'nt be included in your csproj so when building the project they wont get compiled. But you might be able to figure that out in a different way

Comment: Yes, but it needs to be compiled in though @JochemVanHespen

Comment: I figure you can use basic file manipulation to add those includes to the csproj

Comment: @JochemVanHespen, the idea here is to automate the process, not to manually add files to a project :-)

Comment: Yes that I understand. You can also use the [codedom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/compile-code-using-compiler) for this

Comment: Not sure if this solves your problem, I stumbled upon it when looking for something similar. https://github.com/zijianhuang/openapiclientgen